# run NanoHttpd as a root

Tags: android, root, nanohttpd

I would like to run [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) on an Android (KitKat 4.4) device and bind it to port 80.

I understand that I can only bind to port 80 as a root user. My device has been rooted and I can fire up a process with superuser privileges successfully, like so:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

This [blog post](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/) shows me how to write a file, by using the `getOutputStream()` method of `Process`.

However, I would like to run NanoHttpd within the rooted process. Is that possible? Or am I restricted to shell commands? Or can I start my app from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your app in a script by using the following command (with superuser rights):

```
am start -n your.package.name/.YourActivity
```

Replace `your.package.name` and `.YourActivity` accordingly.

To use root shell in java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream doutps = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
doutps.writeBytes("yourcommand" + "\n");
doutps.flush();
doutps.writeBytes("exit\n");
doutps.flush();
p.WaitFor();
doutps.close();
try { p.destroy(); } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Again, replace `yourcommand` with your desired command.

You can use **any** command that you can use in the root shell, no matter what the command is and how it is constructed. If you need multiple commands, just repeat following lines for every command:

```
doutps.writeBytes("yourcommand" + "\n");
doutps.flush();
```